# Angular Cypress component testing error: Unexpected framework angular, expected one of create-react-app, nuxt, react, vue-cli, next, vue

Tags: angular, docker, cypress, snapshot-testing

I wish to run my Cypress snapshot tests for my Angular app in a docker container to maintain consistency and make my visual tests less brittle. I am using the Cypress Docker container:

```docker
FROM cypress/included:10.1.0
```

Here is my `cypress.config.ts` file:

```typescript
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin } from '@simonsmith/cypress-image-snapshot/plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    component: {
        devServer: {
            framework: 'angular',
            bundler: 'webpack',
        },
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            on('task', {
                log(message) {
                    console.log(message);
                    return null;
                },
            });
            addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin(on);
        },
        specPattern: '**/*.cy.ts',
    },
});
```

I'm able to build the Docker image, but when I try to run the container, I get the following error

```
Your configFile threw an error from: cypress.config.js

We stopped running your tests because your config file crashed.

Error: Unexpected framework angular, expected one of create-react-app, nuxt, react, vue-cli, next, vue
```

I saw a resource that says:

> Cypress component testing does not officially support the Angular framework out of the box for its `devServer` configuration. This limitation means you cannot directly specify `framework: 'angular'` in the `cypress.config.js` or `cypress.config.ts` file and expect Cypress to automatically manage the Angular development server for component tests.

I'm not sure if it is right. I would think component testing for Angular would be a pretty important feature and running them in a Docker container should be possible.

Is there a way to do this or am I out of luck?

Comment: It _is_ [currently supported](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/overview#Supported-Frameworks), but bear in mind 10.1.0 is three major versions behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress 10.1.0 does not support Angular Component testing, as that was not added until [Cypress 10.5.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#10-5-0).

Upgrade your Cypress docker image to at least [`cypress/included:10.5.0`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/cypress/included/10.5.0/images/sha256-a00af475fe7d953f1179f93f967faba9b0017286d7508b6979e4a2bf1c3cb8fc?context=explore) to gain support for Angular Component testing.